# Closure compiler annotations for an object containing a constructor function

Tags: javascript, types, module, google-closure-compiler

I'm trying to typecheck a library that returns an Object of constructor functions.  With the following code Closure errors with:

```
./my-app.js:11: ERROR - Cannot call non-function type Foo.Wheel
const wheel = new Foo.Wheel();
               ^
```

Here's the code structure:

**my-app-code.js** - The code I'm using

```
const Foo = /** @type{!Foo.Module} */ require('foo');
const wheel = new Foo.Wheel();
wheel.rotate();
```

**externs-foo.js** - Closure externs for the Foo library

```
/** @const */
const Foo = {};


/** @record */
Foo.Module = function() {};

/** @type {!Foo.Wheel} */
Foo.Module.prototype.Wheel;

/** @constructor */
Foo.Wheel = function() {};

/**
* @returns {void}
*/
Foo.Wheel.prototype.rotate = function() {};
```

**foo/index.js** - corresponds to Foo.Module type.

```
module.exports = {
  Wheel: require("./wheel"),
};
```

**foo/wheel.js** - corresponds to Foo.Wheel.

```
function Wheel() {}

Wheel.prototype.rotate = function() {};

module.exports = Wheel;
```

I tried one variation on `externs-foo.js` with the following results.

Make `Foo.module.prototype.Wheel` a function

```
/** @return {!Foo.Wheel} */
Foo.Module.prototype.Wheel = function() {};
```

Errors with:

```
my-app.js:11: ERROR - Expected a constructor but found type function(this:Foo.Module):Foo.Wheel.
const wheel = new Foo.Wheel();

my-app.js:13: ERROR - Property rotate never defined on module$myapp_Foo of type Foo.Module
wheel.rotate();
```

Comment: In the externs, try doing Foo.Module.prototype.Wheel = Foo.Wheel;

Comment: The annotations "@type {!Foo.Wheel}" and "@return {!Foo.Wheel}" won't work because the first says that the object is an instance of Foo.Wheel and the second says that the function returns that instance. You don't want any of those scenarios, what you actually want is really the constructor.

Another option would be using the type {function(new:!Foo.Wheel)}, which says that the function is in fact a constructor that instantiates a Foo.Wheel object.

Comment: Nice, thank you.  `@type {function(new:Foo.Wheel)}` worked without the exclamation point.  If you want to write an answer I'll accept it or I can write it up in a day or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm aware of two solutions to this issue:

1. Declaring `Foo.Module.prototype.Wheel = Foo.Wheel;` in the externs file.
2. Use `@type {function(new:Foo.Wheel)}`, which says that the function is in fact a constructor that instantiates a Foo.Wheel object.

I prefer solution #1 because it declares a reference to the constructor function, so the compiler will allow me to access properties of the constructor (e.g. static methods). IIRC this can't be done in solution #2.

The annotations `@type {!Foo.Wheel}` and `@return {!Foo.Wheel}` won't work because they refer to an instance of `Foo.Wheel` and what you actually want is the constructor itself.